# Call JavaScript function after 1 second One Time

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have successfully managed to make a div hide on click after 400 milliseconds using a setInterval function. My issue is that it runs continually, I only need the function to execute once. After a quick search I discovered that the setInterval can be stopped by clearInterval. Am I using this incorrectly? The closeAnimation function is being executed on click. I modelled my code after the code on this page: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

```
function closeAnimation() {
    setInterval(function(){hide()}, 400);
    clearInterval(stopAnimation);
}

var stopAnimation = setInterval({hide()}, 400);
```

Comment: Rather than use `setInterval()`, use `setTimeout()`. Timeout runs only once after however many miliseconds.

Comment: [MDN: window.setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout)

Comment: As Stijn and Carl said, use MDN (Mozilla Developer Network). They have great documentation for all kinds of web developing, and they do not focus on just Mozilla vendor (i.e. "moz" prefixed functions and attribtues)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If it needs to run just once you can use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)

```js
setTimeout(function () {
  console.log('Hello world')
}, 1000)

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('Foo bar')
}, 1000)
```

Comment: The setTimeout link actually linked me to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval

Answer (score 7):

You should use setTimeout():

```html
setTimeout(function() {
    getScore(); 
    getResult(); 
}, 1800000);
```

The '1800000' is the time in milliseconds after which you want this function to execute. In this case, 30 minutes.